# use zend framework in to develop Rest api in php

Tags: php, mongodb, zend-framework, frameworks, zend-rest

I want to build Rest apis in php and want to use MongoDB. 
I found out that zend is widely used and also have good documentation.

But i couldn't find out that Zend framework has a support for MongoDB or not?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used ZEND so far, just know it is written in php. So to access mongodb you maybe could use the links which you find on following site: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php-libraries/

Comment: This is the list of frameworks which supports MongoDB and php website development, Not to develop REST apis.

Comment: Yes, I thought the question 'But i couldn't find out that Zend framework has a support for MongoDB or not?' pointed to, whether there is a driver or similar for MongoDB or not. Guess on the other part I cannot help more.